# "I have gained a lot of experience" or "I gained"?

Tags: tense

I am preparing for an interview, and I want to say that "I have gained a lot of experience."  Is that right, or should I say "I gained"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I have gained* means you are referring to the experience you gained until today. *I gained* is referring to the experience you gained in the past.

Hardly somebody would think you didn't gain any experience, recently, if you say *I gained*. Saying *I have gained* you are sure they understand you are talking of what you did until nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

So, straight to the answer. I should use the first option (I have gained) because according to the rules of use of and Past Perfect, you use "have" when you do not make when that happened clear.

Exp:
I gained a lot of experience in the last couple of months
I've gained a lot of experience recently

I really hope this helps you out, and good luck in your interview